# How can we know that in an activity which fragment is loaded currently when we come in foreground from background?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity named captureActivity ,which do qr code scanning.when scanning done a fragment opens and display contents of scanning.I have an issue that this activity always opens in background, i open any fragment after scanning.Scanning always open in background.I just want that ones scanning done ,camera should be release until i open that activity again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find current fragment loaded in container by using this:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contanerID)
```

If you are using app fragment or if you are using v4 fragment then use this:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerID);
```